# PHP: How to output email message into paragraphs?

Tags: php, html

How do I get my contact form to output the message in paragraphs rather than just one big block of text? Here's how it looks when the user fills out my form (even though he used carriage return to make paragraphs):

[image]

My process.php code:

```
<?php

$recipient = "johndoe@aol.com";
$subject = "FORM SUBMISSION";

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$replyTo = $_POST['email'];
$sender = "From: $replyTo\r\n";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$whyContact = $_POST['whyContact'];

$sender .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$sender .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n";

$msgBody = "
<html>
<head>
<title>title here</title>
</head>

<style type='text/css'>

body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }

</style>

<body>

<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;font-size:12px;line-height:135%;font-family:'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, sans-serif'>
<tr style='background-color:#F5F5F5'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>Name:</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$firstName $lastName</td>
</tr>
<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>Email:</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$replyTo</td>
</tr>
<tr style='background-color:#F5F5F5'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>What are you contacting us about?</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$whyContact</td>
</tr>
<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>Message:</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$message</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

mail($recipient, $subject, $msgBody, $sender);
?>
```

Comment: You're sending the email as html.. so if you want your text to look like a paragraph.. wrap it in p tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try

```
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
```

PHP new line to BR [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)